# How to disable in ace editor the selection

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

Does anyone know how can I disable the selection of ace.editor? No word selection by mouse and finger.

I tried to use `editor.selection(false);`

but that does not work.

Comment: Also, [this issue](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/issues/266) in the ace github seems to show that you can't do this, but they have workarounds there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can effectively prevent selection by setting the editor to read only then overriding the selection style in the theme:

```
.noselection .ace_marker-layer .ace_selection {
   background: transparent;
}

.noselection .ace_cursor {
   color: transparent;
}
```

Then just add the `noselection` class to your ace container div.

This won't actually prevent the user selecting anything, but there will be no visual indication that its happening; which for all intents and purposes is pretty much the same thing.

Lots more detail here:

https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/wiki/Creating-or-Extending-an-Edit-Mode

There is also this approach:

https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/issues/266

Answer (score 10):

```
editor.getSession().selection.on('changeSelection', function (e)
{
    editor.getSession().selection.clearSelection();
});
```

Comment: @Unheilig I cannot explain exactly why, because I've just started with ace three days ago and I don't know the internals, but I can confirm that it works for me. My guess is it will immediately deselect if you try to select even a single character.

Answer (score 3):

You can disable the ace editor using below code:

```
editor.setReadOnly(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

editor.setValue(str, -1) // moves cursor to the start

editor.setValue(str, 1) // moves cursor to the end

Comment: Sorry, but this will not dissable the selection.

Comment: To hide cursor and line highlights:editor.setOptions({
    readOnly: true,
    highlightActiveLine: false,
    highlightGutterLine: false
})
editor.renderer.$cursorLayer.element.style.opacity=0                        to make editor non tabbable         editor.textInput.getElement().tabIndex=-1
 or
editor.textInput.getElement().disabled=true                              to disable all shortcuts                               editor.commands.commmandKeyBinding={}

Comment: Thank you, but whatever the reason is, the commands do not work for me.